# PowerShell: Running Script from Visual Studio Code Works, Running from PS Command Line Fails

Tags: powershell, command-line, parameters

I have a PowerShell script that I have developed and tested in Visual Studio Code that runs without error. However, when I attempt to run the same script from a PowerShell command line, it fails with several errors, the first one being a complaint about the use of Param on the first line of the script. I have PS 5.1 installed on my machine.

When launched from the command line, here is what I execute:

`powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File Export_PI.ps1 -Project Catalyst-DHT`

When I run this script from Visual Studio Code, I substitute a hard-coded value in lieu of the parameter `-Project` for testing purposes. When I run it from the PS command line, this is the first error I get:

`Param : The term 'Param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

I have read elsewhere that this typically occurs when Param() is not the first non-commented line in the script. In my script, it is the first non-commented line:

`$ProjectName = Param([String]$Project)`

I'm not a PowerShell guru, so this could well be a newbie mistake. I'm hoping someone can help me figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

> I have PS 5.1 installed on my machine.

is most likely the issue you are having. VSC uses PowerShell Core (6 <=) and not PowerShell Desktop (6 >)

Also the line

```
$ProjectName = Param([String]$Project)
```

is not correct since you don't assign `Param` to a variable but use it as a statement that assigns variables based on the arguments provided. You will want

```
Param([String]$ProjectName)
```

as the first line of your script. Like the error states, `Param` is not the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program when not used alone at the top of a script.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. My effort to assign the parameter value to a variable was wrong. It does raise the question: if I were to pass more than one variable, it seems that I would simply have to extract them in the same order they are applied?

Comment: you can add more objects to `Param` for more arguments like `Param([type]$arg1, [type]$arg2)` etc then access them accordingly with `$arg1` and `$arg2`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.1 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1